# Type-Incomplete Matlab Equality Support

Tags: matlab, types, comparison

Why can't I compare specific types such as, function handles, using the `==` operation in Matlab?

For instance

```
@prod == @sum
```

fails with error

```
Undefined function 'eq' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.
```

Does this mean that this type can support comparison if we just specify overload `==` for `function_handle` types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To test equality of function handles, use the [ISEQUAL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isequal.html) command instead:

```
>> isequal(@prod, @sum)

ans =

     0

>> isequal(@prod, @prod)

ans =

     1
```

Comment: Thanks. Still, is there a reason for Matlab rejecting the use of `==' in this case?

Comment: Figured you might ask again. I really don't know. I tend to use `isequal` more often and restrict `eq` for numeric data types.